# PHP script fails at $mail = new PHPMailer() without error message

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

This is driving me up a wall!

I'm trying to use phpmailer to send e-mail. Here is my code:

```
 print "about to do the require!";
 require_once("$s[phppath]/phpmailer.php");
 print "require has been successful! creating a PHPMailer object!";
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 print "yay!";
```

However, the program never gets to "yay", it dies at line 4 ($mail = new PHPMailer();). Most maddening is that no error message is displayed, even though php is running with display_errors = On. To test this, I threw in some obvious errors, like skipping semi-colons at the end of lines, and I immediately get an error message about this.

What the heck is going on here?

**Edited**
I modified the code like this:

```
require_once("$s[phppath]/phpmailer.php");
try {
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Still no dice.

Comment: enable the error_reporting('E_ALL') and see what the error.

Comment: Wow, that nailed the error message problem... I feel really stupid now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there were two parts to this question:

1) Why no error messages? I feel very, very stupid about this one, because though I had display_errors turned on, my own script actually disabled error_reporting. Thank you Pathik Ghandi for pointing out this very simple fix. I can be quite special at times.

2) Why was PHPMailer not working? Because apparently PHPMailer now requires TWO files instead of one: class.phpmailer.php is not enough. You now also need PHPMailerAutoload.php. Hope this helps someone down the line!

Answer (score 2):

I am using PHPMailer also. Now in 2018 Version 6.05.

I was also in trouble with creation of $mail = new PHPMailer; I always saw the message that the class could not be created. But I was sure the file with the class was included.

What I found out, was that there is a namespace used within the class PHPMailer.

So the new object does not exist as "PHPMailer" but as class within the namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer ! (not to be confused with folders of your installation).

**What finally worked for me was to write the following line:
 
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;**

// You need to add the namespace part after new and before class PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing out $s[phppath] to make sure you are getting the right path. Redownload and reupload the phpMailer lib. Try using `require` instead of `require_once`. Try using `include` instead of `require`. Go into the phpmailer.php file and add in an echo or something to make sure you are actually requiring that file.

To be sure; Are you running some kind of framework? ie Wordpress? If so you may need to set a flag to show PHP error messages. WP: define("WP_DEBUG", true);

Answer (score 0):

Try to call restore_error_handler() function above require.